# how do i Launch the Eclipse WTP workbench?

Tags: eclipse, web-services, eclipse-wtp

I am learning how to debug web services using the web services toolkit. In these instructions, step 1 says "[Launch the Eclipse WTP workbench](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.0/tutorials/WebServiceExplorer/WebServiceExplorer.html)." How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Web Tool Platform (aka WTP). You can download this edition from here : http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/

btw it`s 7 years old article, i am not sure if it still bring any benefit as Java EE standarts and Eclipse IDE evolved...

Comment: i think it is installed with my version of eclipse (helios enterprise edition). how can i launch it?

Comment: If it's installed properly, you just need to launch Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I did "Window -> Perspective -> Open Perspective -> Other -> Web".  This gave me buttons I wanted.  Then I hit the button for "Launch the Web Services Explorer".